# Autorun file when you connect to vagrant server

Tags: javascript, ruby, vagrant

I am currently working on a server where I want to autorun a file whenever I connect to the server myself. Example; I start the server and when I connect to it I want it to run a backup. My server is running on another computer and I connect to it from my main computer to save performance. The thing is that I also want to be able to work inside the server from my main computer. Example; The server is running on PC1 and I want to have access to the server from PC2 via vagrant.

The server is run by vagrant.

I have some experience within - Ruby, C++, Vagrant, javascript and SQL if this is helpful for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to connect to the server remotely via the vagrant environment using `ssh vagrant@192.168.x.x` where the x.x is the ip of the local computer.

Example

IP to the vagrant server is 192.168.192.192
On my main computer I run the command `ssh vagrant@192.168.192.192` and I login with the default password.